# Trigger action in Python Flask depending on debug mode state

Tags: python, debugging, flask

I have a [Flask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) application, and I want to trigger some action:

To load small sample data if in debug mode, but big data if not in debug mode.

Here is how I give info to Flask about debug mode:

```
app = FlaskApp()
app.config.update({
  'DEBUG': True,
  'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': True })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if app.debug:
    load_small_data()
else:
    load_big_data()
```

Comment: the console says debug mode is on, but the value of app.debug returned false